# Nginx configuration for finding index.html

Tags: nginx

I am trying to accomplish the following behavior:

In the file structure

```
/var/html/jpmelos.com/
- index.html
- public/
  - index.html
```

If I reach for `http://jpmelos.com`, I want to get `public/index.html` if the file exists, and if it does not exist, I want to prompt the user for username and password and get `index.html`. Same behavior if reaching for `http://jpmelos.com/index.html`. Public folder is checked and matched first, then protected folder with password.

I include this configuration file in the `http` block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name jpmelos.com;

    location / {
        root /var/html/jpmelos.com/public;
        index index.html;
        try_files $request_uri @redirect;
    }

    location @redirect {
        auth_basic on;
        auth_basic_user_file /htpasswd/jpmelos;

        root /var/html/jpmelos.com;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

The resultant behavior when I reach `http://jpmelos.com/index.html` is correct, and I get the file `public/index.html`. But when I reach for `http://jpmelos.com`, it returns a `403 Forbidden`. I am running Ubuntu 15.10, Nginx 1.11.1.

This is confusing because, since the file can be returned from `http://jpmelos.com/index.html`, we know this is not forbidden. And the configuration correctly sets `index index.html`, and the file is there.

So, what am I missing?

---

Also, a side question: if I change `root /var/html/jpmelos.com/public;` to `alias /var/html/jpmelos.com/public;`, it doesn't match anymore, and returns `404 Not Found`. Why is that?

Comment: Which OS? Which `nginx` version?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my configuration and achieved what I wanted:

```
server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name jpmelos.com;
    root /var/html/jpmelos.com/public;

    index index.html;
    autoindex off;

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ @redirect;
    }   

    location @redirect {
        auth_basic on; 
        auth_basic_user_file /htpasswd/jpmelos;

        root /var/html/jpmelos.com;
    }
}
```

Move the first root directive to the `server` block, just because it is a good practice. Then, move the `index` directive also, to avoid repetition. Then, change the `try_files` directive. This will try `$uri` file, then the `$uri` **directory** using the `index` directive, and then redirect.

Upon redirect, set the auth settings and update the root to the new value, just for that `location` block.

Comment: Good work, +1. Besides: Next time it would be great if you could answer to questions raised by people who are trying to help you. Otherwise, this becomes a bit point- and senseless.